# Tune PostgreSQL by changing config parameters

Tags: performance, postgresql, configuration, config, postgresql-9.6

I have *postgresql 9.6* which is runnig on ubuntu server 16.04 with `122gb RAM`, `320gb SSD`, `18 vCPU` on AWS. I want to know what parameters do I need to change in `postgresql.config` file according to these resource in order to get high performance? 
How to force postgresql to load the data in memory as much as possible?

Answer (score 1):

For quick start you can use pgtune util or web alternative http://pgtune.leopard.in.ua.
Let's assume you write web app:

```
# WARNING
# this tool not being optimal 
# for very high memory systems

max_connections = 200
shared_buffers = 31232MB
effective_cache_size = 93696MB
work_mem = 159907kB
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this tool but it is informing that is not optimal for high memory systems! are there some references that explain what is the best way of changing config parameters?

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server and http://www.revsys.com/writings/postgresql-performance.html explain the most important params and initial steps to tune postgresql.